# Sympy multiset_partitions : Obtain multiplicities?

Tags: python, sympy, multiset

in simpy, there is a wanderfull code that allows to obtain partitions of a multiset. See the exemple from [the documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html#sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_partitions):

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_partitions
for i in multiset_partitions([0,0,1]):
    print(i)
```

outputs :

```
[[0, 0, 1]]
[[0, 0], [1]]
[[0, 1], [0]] *
[[0], [0], [1]]
```

This outputs the **set** of the partitions of the multiset. Is there, somewhere in sympy, a way i can obtain the **multiset** of partitions of the multiset ? The problem i have is exactly the same as [this question in ruby stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215165/yielding-partitions-of-a-multiset-with-ruby), the fact is that the set of parts of the multiset that i highlighted with a `*` should come with multiplicity 2.

Maybe the corrsponding multiplicities can be calculated otherwise ?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that by making the elements unique, performing the regular partition and replacing each element with its original, produced something that seems reasonable:

**Simple solution** (does not identify multiplicity automatically):

```py
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_partitions

A = [0, 0, 1]
B = [i for i in range(len(A))]  # make each element unique
for i in multiset_partitions(B):
    partition = [[A[b] for b in x] for x in i]  # replace each b with A[b].
    print(partition)
```

Which produces:

```py
[[0, 0, 1]]
[[0, 0], [1]]
[[0, 1], [0]]
[[0], [0, 1]]
[[0], [0], [1]]
```

**Less simple solution** (calculates multiplicities on its own slowly):

```py
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_partitions

A = [0]*5+[1]*5
B = [i for i in range(len(A))]
final_multiset = dict()
n = 0
for i in multiset_partitions(B):
    n += 1
    partition = sorted([sorted([A[b] for b in x]) for x in i])

    # lists are not hashable so we need to store them as sorted tuples if we want to check equality
    hashable_partition = tuple(tuple(b for b in x) for x in partition)

    # append it to a dictionary that keeps track of multiplicities
    if hashable_partition in final_multiset:
        final_multiset[hashable_partition] += 1
    else:
        final_multiset[hashable_partition] = 1


for k_tuple, v in final_multiset.items():
    # convert tuple back to list for easy reading
    k_list = [[b for b in x] for x in k_tuple]
    print(k_list)
    print(v)
```

The above takes the same time for any set A but becomes unusable for len(A)>11. I am certain this is correct. Use this to validate the code below.

**Advanced solution** (calculates multiplicities on its own quickly):

Lastly, if you don't want to evaluate all permutations, I found a formula that seems to work. I am not sure that it is correct but it seemed to produce the same results as the above for about 10 different values of A that I tried. This is as fast as OP's code snippet.

```py
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_partitions
from sympy.functions.combinatorial.factorials import factorial


# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374185/does-python-have-a-function-which-computes-multinomial-coefficients
def multinomial(lst):
    res, i = 1, sum(lst)
    i0 = lst.index(max(lst))
    for a in lst[:i0] + lst[i0+1:]:
        for j in range(1, a+1):
            res *= i
            res //= j
            i -= 1
    return res


def get_multiplicity_of_partition(A, partition):
    partition = sorted([sorted([b for b in x]) for x in partition])  # sort everything
    partition_tuple = list(tuple(b for b in x) for x in partition)
    multiplicity = 1

    # permute all indistinguishable elements and divide by how many of that element is in a subset
    for number in set(A):
        numerator = []  # denominator values of a multinomial
        for subset in partition_tuple:
            numerator.append(subset.count(number))  # 0 = number
        multiplicity *= multinomial(numerator)

    # permute all indistinguishable subsets
    prev_subset = []
    num_repetitions = 1
    for subset in partition_tuple + [[]]:  # add last subset so it finishes the last one
        if prev_subset == subset:
            num_repetitions += 1
        else:
            multiplicity /= factorial(num_repetitions)
            num_repetitions = 1
            prev_subset = subset
    return multiplicity


if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = [0]*5 + [1]*5
    for partition in multiset_partitions(A):
        print(partition)
        m = get_multiplicity_of_partition(A, partition)
        print(m)
```

**Explanation:**

The multiplicity of a partition seemed to be = product(# permutations of number i (treating instances of number i as indistinguishable if they are in the same set))/product(multiplicity of unique subset j).

Hopefully I can provide a few examples of how to calculate it by hand:

Example 1: `[[0], [0]]` has multiplicity (2!)/(2!) = 1 since there are 2 zeros in different sets but those 2 sets are the same.

Example 2: `[[0, 1], [0, 1]]` has multiplicity (2!)(2!)/(2!) = 2 since there are 2 zeros in the partition each in different sets and 2 ones, but the set `[0, 1]` is repeated.

Example 3: `[[2], [0, 2, 2], [0, 2, 2], [1, 1]]` has multiplicity (2!)(2!/2!)(4!/2!/2!)/(2!) = 6 since there are 2 zeros, 2 ones in the same set and 4 twos, 2 of which are in the same set and the other 2 are in their own set. And since `[0, 2, 2]` are repeated.

**Final note:**

If the above does produce incorrect results, I won't be able to sleep at night. So for my sanity, please don't let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: This is exactly what i try to avoid: In this way, i have to use a Counter() object on it to obtain the multiplicities. Suppose now that len(A) = 20 or 30, and the problem become a lot harder. But this is a 'right' result.

Comment: Think about it that way : As you understood corretly, there are a lot of duplicates in the multipartition i want. If you explicitely exposes all these duplicates, the size of the set explodes. On the other hand, if we cleverly count multiplicities, the size of the partition stays smaller.

Comment: @Irnv, I can update the answer to calculate the multiplicity if you want. My code begins to become unusable if len(A)>11 however. Note, even using your snippet and removing the print statement, the code becomes unusable if len(A)>14 for the values of A that I tried. With your snippet, I think you would need A to contain only 2 or 3 unique elements if you want to reach len(A)=25 before the head death of the universe. What kind of elements are you planning to have in A?

Comment: Well, the elements of A are given from [0,1,...,d-1] for d = 2, 3, maximum 4 for applications that i have currently. I mainly test with d = 2 (so only 0 and 1 inside A), and len(A) up to 41 within a few seconds of computations. Did not test higher values of d yet, but i will somedays.. The goal is here to obtain the multiplicity without looping on all possibilities.

Comment: Ok, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @Irnv, I managed to produce something faster. I was literally typing here that I was going to give up but then I tried this last algorithm for the multiplicity of a partition. It seemed to produce correct results for the limited tests that I tried.